# Unable to create bucket in cloud storage

Tags: url

When try to create bucket , selecting cloud storage-->storage browser--> create bucket, one window comes up and vanishes and also getting below error message

URL not found

We couldn't find what you were looking for. Try one of the links below.
 Google Developers Console Home
 Google Cloud Platform
 Google Developers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a technical issue on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

From the source it's trying to execute bucketListCtrl.openNewBucketDialog()
This should throw up a dialogue window. If it is flashing then it is trying.

Firstly, have you tried another browser ?  Another physical client ?
You need to assume it is a problem on the client side and then try and prove this. "Forget about the site" and try again.

A workaround is gsutil, I am pretty sure this is a browser/script issue, although a backend DNS issue could be implicated, I would first suspect the URL to be mangled by something locally. Seriously, move to another computer and try it.

Comment: I tried through another machine ,still not able successful. Am using windows 8 machine and internet explorer 11

Comment: OK, do you have gsutil ?  Or can you start an instance, install gsutil and try this from the command line (work, I know).  Are both the machines windows 8 and ie11 ?  What happens for Firefox, say ?   You also need to try from outside your network.  This is where RDP to another country is useful to rule out the geographical aspect and any firewall "re-writes".